# curl PUT data from a huge file?

Tags: bash, curl

I have some nasty curl with ntlm authentication and i need to PUT/send data from some file to server. This is how it looks like. My problem is how to change that data to be read from file easly?

I'm using bash there now.

```
curl -v -X PUT http://server:port/databases/test/docs/testID -d "{ FirstName: 'Bob', LastName: 'Smith', Address: '5 Elm St' }" --ntlm --user 'username:pass'
```

I'm wondering how should i change that data in param -d with a file. Preferably not just echo-ed from certain path? I would rather use some option and just pass a file path

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use a file as data by passing `-d @/path/to/file` (or `-d @-` to read from stdin).